# Does setting workflow variable count as item modification?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I am currently building a workflow that will require changing workflow variables However when the workflow runs I am receiving the email it sends out three times.
The only thing I can think of is that setting variables is acting as item modification and causing the workflow to run again so I have had a look online to see if this is the case but I can't seem to find an answer on this thus hoping someone on here could clarify this for me.
Kind Regards

Comment: Changing workflow variables will not run your workflow again.

Comment: Are you updating any other fields in the list as part of your workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing workflow variables will not run your workflow again. If your workflow is running on item change, then before sending email you can add IF condition to check whether you have sent email before or not. For that you can add one more field in your list(Choice or Yes/No field).

Implement something like this in your workflow:
(considering isEmailSent is your field)

```
If isEmailSent equals No
  Send Email
  Set isEmailSent to Yes
```